# Rbenv unable to find Yarn during Capistrano deployment

Tags: yarnpkg, rbenv, capistrano3

I've been using Capistrano for deployment of my Rails app. It is failing on the following step:

```
   01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /var/www/bubblin.io/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
    ✔ 01 marvin@bubblin.io 1.053s
00:26 yarn:install
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec yarn install --production
      01 rbenv: yarn: command not found

$HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec yarn install --production
      01 rbenv: yarn: command not found
#<Thread:0x00007fb9b626fcd8@/Users/sa/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.17.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from /Users/sa/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.17.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/sa/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.17.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as marvin@bubblin.io: yarn exit status: 127 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
yarn stdout: rbenv: yarn: command not found
yarn stderr: Nothing written
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as marvin@bubblin.io: yarn exit status: 127
yarn stdout: rbenv: yarn: command not found
yarn stderr: Nothing written
```

I ssh'ed into the server and tried the following, which works:

```
$ yarn install --production
yarn install v1.10.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Nothing to install.
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 0.06s.
```

But when I prefix the same command with `rbenv exec` it fails.

```
$ rbenv exec yarn install --production
rbenv: yarn: command not found
```

All dependencies appear to be installed correctly, but `rbenv` isn't able to find `yarn` for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `yarn` is nodejs package manager, should not run via `rbenv exec` perhaps?

So, in this case, you could simply use it from regular shell rather than rbenv.
For example, try to create task like the following should do the job.

```
desc "Yarn Install"
task :yarn_install do
  on roles(:all) do |host|
    execute :yarn, :install, "--production"
  end
end
```

Then, run it with
`bundle exec cap production yarn_install`

Or, invoke the task from another task you have etc.

Update:

If not using yarn,

In Gemfile, remove or comment 'capistrano-yarn'

```
#gem 'capistrano-yarn'
```

In Capfile, remove or comment 'capistrano/yarn'

```
#require 'capistrano/yarn'
```

For creating a new project:

`rails new <name> --skip-yarn`

But, on existing project, set `webpacker.check_yarn_integrity` to `false` in app env files (i.e. app/config/development.rb app/config/production.rb)

```
config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = false
```

Find `javascript_pack_tag` or `stylesheet_pack_tag` in `app/views/*` path, then comment them out, like so:

```
<%# javascript_pack_tag "" %>
<%# stylesheet_pack_tag "" %>
```

Comment: hm. I was trying to use the https://github.com/j-arnaiz/capistrano-yarn extension to avoid handling yarn, but then I realized I don't need yarn for my rails app at all. So I'm now looking for a way to rails not ask for yarn at all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52905703/how-to-remove-yarn-from-a-rails-app-completely

Comment: @marvindanig I see. I have updated the answer for handle your situation, hope it helps.