# How to remove Yarn from a Rails app completely?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, yarnpkg

I'm building a Rails 5.1.x rails app with `jQuery` and a few other libraries. Rails is insisting on having Yarn on, which is fine on development machine but I cannot have it on production.

Is there a way to not have rails use Yarn by default? Remove `yarn.lock` and `node_modules` and everything else that comes with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a rails project, you can add `--skip-yarn` as `rails new app_path --skip-yarn`.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the following lines from the files

bin/setup.rb and bin/update.rb

```
-  # Install JavaScript dependencies if using Yarn
-  system('bin/yarn')
```

config/initializers/assets.rb

```
# Add Yarn node_modules folder to the asset load path.
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
```

Comment: Please explain why one should do that

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 5.2.x and 6.0.x if you create new Rails app with --skip-yarn flag, it still adds a check if yarn is installed. 
So when you run `rails webpacker:install`, the result could be

```
Yarn not installed. Please download and install Yarn from https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/
```

The solution is to add these four lines at the end of Rakefile, right after `Rails.application.load_tasks`:

```
# Replace yarn with npm
Rake::Task['webpacker:yarn_install'].clear
Rake::Task['webpacker:check_yarn'].clear
Rake::Task.define_task('webpacker:verify_install' => ['webpacker:check_npm'])
Rake::Task.define_task('webpacker:compile' => ['webpacker:npm_install'])
```

This will remove check for yarn, and you can use only webpack.

**EDIT:** 
If you use assets compilation, or you want to manage client-side libraries, such as React, Angular or Vue, I would actually **recommend** to use **yarn** instead of npm, because Rails 6 seems to be deeply integrated with yarn. It will call yarn on server start, and also on assets compilation. Instead of doing hard work replacing yarn with npm, you could just accept the choice of Rails repo's developers.

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up to anyone reading this question in the future: [Max Popoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59374538/5220146) only works if you define the new rake tasks referenced in their Rakefile first. There's a little more information on this [blog post](https://itnext.io/how-to-use-webpacker-with-npm-instead-of-yarn-a8a764e3a8ab) but essentially, you need to add a file like this:

```
# lib/tasks/webpacker.rake

namespace :webpacker do
  task :check_npm do
    begin
      npm_version = `npm --version`
      raise Errno::ENOENT if npm_version.blank?
      version = Gem::Version.new(npm_version)

      package_json_path = Pathname.new("#{Rails.root}/package.json").realpath
      npm_requirement = JSON.parse(package_json_path.read).dig('engines', 'npm')
      requirement = Gem::Requirement.new(npm_requirement)

      unless requirement.satisfied_by?(version)
        $stderr.puts "Webpacker requires npm #{requirement} and you are using #{version}" && exit!
      end
    rescue Errno::ENOENT
      $stderr.puts 'npm not installed'
      $stderr.puts 'Install NPM https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm' && exit!
    end
  end

  task :npm_install do
    system 'npm install'
  end
end
```